# Strange issue with "denyinterfaces" in access point config

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi running raspbian stretch, which connects to an existing WiFi network using wpa-supplicant on wlan1 (a usb dongle), while wlan0 (the built-in radio) works as an access point.

I had trouble getting the access point side to work, until I read some advice which said to put `denyinterfaces wlan0` in `/etc/dhdpcd.conf`, directly above the first static ip configuration. When I boot it up with this in place, the access point works, i.e. I can see the SSID from another device. Without the line I do not see the SSID at all.

However, with that line in place it does not give out DHCP over wlan0. I have to comment it out and then restart the DHCP server, and only then does it give out addresses.

So, I currently go through this process whenever I need to reboot. I uncomment the line, reboot, then comment it out and restart DHCP.

It would be nice to avoid having to do this rigmarole, especially as we are prone to power cuts!

Any ideas what could be wrong with the configuration? Let me know if I should post any files or the output of any commands, to clarify the situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that wlan0 was not getting an ip. The static ip set in /etc/dhcpd.conf was not being applied (presumably because of the denyinterfaces).

I fixed it by adding this to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.2.1/24
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.2.1
  dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1 8.8.4.4
```

I had read that in Raspian Stretch it was not necessary to do this as everything was handled in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. I guess that must not be true.